# type TimestampType of colum not supported

Tags: scala, apache-spark, linear-regression

i use spark with scala a have problem in type TimestampType

```
 object regressionLinear {
  case class X(
                time:String,nodeID: Int, posX: Double,posY: Double,
                speed: Double,period: Int)

  def main (args: Array[String]) {

Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF)

/**
  * Read the input data
  */
var dataset = "C:\\spark\\A6-d07-h08.csv"
if (args.length > 0) {
  dataset = args(0)
}

val spark = SparkSession
  .builder
  .appName("regressionsol")
  .master("local[4]")
  .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._


val data = spark.sparkContext.textFile(dataset)
     .map(line=>line.split(","))
.map(userRecord => (userRecord(0).trim.toString,
      userRecord(1).trim.toInt, userRecord(2).trim.toDouble,userRecord(3).trim.toDouble,userRecord(4).trim.toDouble,userRecord(5).trim.toInt))
.toDF("time","nodeID","posX", "posY","speed","period").withColumn("time", $"time".cast("timestamp"))


val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols( Array(
    "time","nodeID","posX", "posY","speed","period"))
  .setOutputCol("features")


val lr = new LinearRegression()
  .setLabelCol("period")
  .setFeaturesCol("features")
   .setRegParam(0.1)
  .setMaxIter(100)
  .setSolver("l-bfgs")

val steps = 
  Array(assembler, lr)

val pipeline = new Pipeline()
  .setStages(steps)

val Array(training, test) = data.randomSplit(Array(0.75, 0.25), seed = 12345)


val model = pipeline.fit {
  training
}

val holdout = model.transform(test)
holdout.show(20)

val prediction = holdout.select("prediction", "period","nodeID").orderBy(abs(col("prediction")-col("period")))
prediction.show(20)


val rm = new RegressionMetrics(prediction.rdd.map{
  x =>  (x(0).asInstanceOf[Double], x(1).asInstanceOf[Double])
})
println(s"RMSE = ${rm.rootMeanSquaredError}")
println(s"R-squared = ${rm.r2}")

spark.stop()
  }

}
```

it is error

> > Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data type TimestampType of column time is not supported.
> >         at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler.transformSchema(VectorAssembler.scala:124)
> >         at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline$$anonfun$transformSchema$4.apply(Pipeline.scala:184)
> >         at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline$$anonfun$transformSchema$4.apply(Pipeline.scala:184)
> >         at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldl(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:57)
> >         at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:66)
> >         at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foldLeft(ArrayOps.scala:186)
> >         at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline.transformSchema(Pipeline.scala:184)
> >         at org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineStage.transformSchema(Pipeline.scala:74)
> >         at org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline.fit(Pipeline.scala:136)
> >         at regressionLinear$.main(regressionLinear.scala:100)
> >         at regressionLinear.main(regressionLinear.scala)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VectorAssembler` accepts only numeric columns. Other type of columns have to be encoded first. And considering that you apply `LinearRegression` data has to be encoded anyway.

Exact steps will depend on the domain specific knowledge:

- If you expect linear trend based on time cast field to numeric first.
- If you expect some type of seasonal effects you might have to extract individual components (day of week, hour / time of day, month and so on), and typically apply `StringIndexer` + `OneHotEncoder.